# Android Wear: How to send multiple items with MessageApi?

Tags: android, api, message, wear-os

So i want to use the MessageApi and not the DataApi to send multiple items to the wearable. However the sendMessage() of the MessageApi only allows a byte array to be sent.

For reference:

```
Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient,
                             String id,
                             String path,
                             byte[] bytes)
```

My guess would be to create an array of byte arrays and then serialize that into one big byte array and send it off.

To make things clearer these are the steps in pseudo code:

```
byte[][] arrayOfByteArrays;
String a --> convert to byte[];
Bitmap b --> convert to byte[];

Add a and b byte[]'s to arrayOfByteArrays;
Serialize arrayOfByteArrays to just a byte[] and send it off;
```

Is this the correct approach? or Should I just call `sendMessage()` multiple times? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is more efficient (battery, bandwidth, ...) to send one message instead of multiple ones. However, there may be other factors involved in your specific case that may warrant sending multiple messages. Looking at your pseudo code, I noticed you are also trying to send a bitmap using the MessageApi. That, in general, is not the best approach to send across an image, or other types of assets; you can use [Assets](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Asset) or you can use [ChannelApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelApi). Otherwise, the approach of serializing a bunch of small objects and putting them into one byte array and then desrializing at the other end would work; one simple way to do so (if dealing with simple objects) is to use json as a serialization means.

Comment: Thank you, I think `ChannelApi` might be what I'm looking for. However, to send multiple items through ChannelApi I'll still have to use `sendFile()` multiple times right?

Comment: Correct. If I were to send the type of things that you had mentioned, I would use the ChannelApis to send files and would use MessageApis to send small pieces of messages (including small arrays of strings, etc). Note that ChannelApis has a low-level APIs as well that can allow you open an OutputStream on the sender side and an InputStream on the receiver side to send bits through but that is more useful for real-time transfer rather than sending a file.